# Scheduled task run .bat once a week Win7

Tags: windows, batch-file, settings, scheduled-tasks, task

I need to have a .bat run once a week when I log onto the computer. I tried several things and if im not logged on then the .bat fails. but works if I am logged on when its scheduled to start. What setting in windows 7 scheduled task makes is keep trying untill I log in? Or am I doing something incorrect?

My settings:

```
GENERAL:
Run only when user is logged on (Yes)
Configure for: Win7, Win Server 2008 R2

TRIGGER:
Begin the task: On a schedule
Weekly (Yes)
Recur Every : 1 weeks on Tues @ 8p
Enabled (Yes)

SETTINGS:
Allow task to be run on demand (Yes)
Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed (Yes)
If the task fails, restart every... 5 min up to 50 times for 3 days
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooh - sore point! Massive argument with the expert System Administrator at my last job when she couldn't arrange for a scheduled job to start unless the user was logged in. Claimed it was a well-known problem that NO-ONE had ever solved - not even Microsoft (who'd published a fix nearly three years earlier.)

So, I'm not surprised that you're having trouble when an EXPERT (on everything) who'd won industry awards for the quality of her work couldn't get it going.

I think the major problem is in the data you've posted,

```
GENERAL:
Run only when user is logged on (Yes)
```

Which just might mean "Run only when the user is logged in."

So - if you'd explain what it is you want to do, we might be able to progress to some conclusion.

Do you want the process to run at a particular time on a particular day, whether the user is logged in or not, or do you want it to run IF the user logs in on that day (but no others) or every 7th day the user logs in or some other condition? Remember - calendar days and work-days are different - public holidays, vacations, whatever come into play...

Comment: Ok, I need it to run when "I" log into the PC once a week and I work rotating turns daylight and afternoon no midnight. So I would like to run it on a tuesday somwhere when one week im going to be logged on and the next it will have to wait an hour so the time I need it to run is at 3:30pm on every tuesday. The file is just a batch file that backs up my databases (3 of them) and images folder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up your task to run as you, regardless if you are logged in?

Control Panel -> Task Scheduler.  Go to the properties of your task, then under the General tab verify that your user account is specified under the "use the following user account".  You will probably also be prompted for your password.